# Does Google Cloud Storage Backup and What Are Prices For 1Tb?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, price

I am wondering does Google Cloud backup there servers. For example has anyone ever lost there data, or maybe is there any off chance that this can happen? Or has Google has a strategy to prevent this. Or is it up to us to make backups?

Also I have another question. I have a site with 1TB of downloadable files. I'm wondering on the cost each month and the bandwidth prices?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unrelated to programming.

Comment: I was directed here by Google Cloud to ask any related questions. If not here then, where?

Comment: *"I was directed here by Google Cloud to ask any related questions."* I sincerely doubt you asked Google Cloud if they back up their data and they said "Go ask Stack Overflow." Do you have a reference?

Comment: When I mean I was directed here by Google Cloud, I mean this was stated on there website. Here is the link on which the page I found it... https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/3466163

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Storage Classes](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes) documentation page:

> All storage classes support:
>
> - Redundant storage. Cloud Storage is designed for 99.999999999% durability.

As for pricing, you can plug your numbers into the [Google Cloud Platform Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/) or look directly at the [Google Cloud Storage Pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing).

Comment: Thanks, just the answer I was looking for.